# React Hooks: App.js state changes and re-renders

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This might be a trivial or baseless question but it is really important to know what's exactly going on as there is no good material or answers about this right now.

Basically, consider this simple example:

`App.js`

```
const [someState, setSomeState] = useState(0)
....
some more state variables and functions
....
<ContextWrapper someState={someState} someFunction={someFunction}>
    <Child1 />
    <Child2 />
</ContextWrapper>
```

`ContextWrapper` is basically another component which has a context which is widely used throughout the entire app components and returns this:

```
<DataContext.Provider value={{ values }}>{props.children}</DataContext.Provider>
```

Now, here are my questions:

1.) Every time I change any state of `App`, there is a re-render and ALL children are re-rendered too. This includes my `ContextWrapper` as well. Isn't this counter-intuitive? Am I doing it wrong and should the `App` component have no state so that no re-renders are triggered?

2.) Is there anything wrong in passing props to `ContextWrapper`?

3.) What are the performance implications of this and how can I stop multiple re-renders of the children components? Is it even necessary to do so or this isn't much of a big deal?

Thanks!

Comment: A change in state requires a re-render. If you have state that's high-up, changing its state will re-render everything below it. If you can put state in lower components without making the code confusing, do it if you can (for similar reasons, good to avoid globals)

Comment: I agree with you. But React docs and general posts always tell to move the state "up". Even more so in the case of hooks and functional components...

Comment: When a component re-renders, then all children of *that* sub-tree will also be re-rendered. It should be noted that the "render" here means during the "render phase" when they are rendered into react's virtual DOM for diff'ing purposes in order to compute the diff that needs to be flushed to the real DOM during the "commit phase". There are mechanisms to further hint to the react frame work when a descendent component shouldn't re-render, i.e. `memo` HOC, other react hooks to memoize passed props/state values, etc... React is optimized to make the virtual DOM and diff'ing fast and efficient.

Comment: I think the point is to lift state up *when it solves a problem*, or makes the code easier, but that doesn't mean it should *always* be done - encapsulate if possible and easy. Still, your question makes an interesting point, having top-level state and then having to go through every single child component seems... off for performance.

Comment: Just saw this, it might be relevant: https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/il2ndq/my_thoughts_on_endless_battle_of_react_state/g3pto0h/ Use context for low-frequency updates, not for main global application state. (but I'm not sure how other state management solutions deal with/cause re-renders)

Comment: While I agree with lifting state up or taking it down according to the best situational use, in this particular case I have lots of functions being accessed by many child components and so I HAVE to keep those functions at the top level parent, which is `App.js` here. Any other ideas or suggestions? I don't want to just simply start using Redux or some other state management tool just because of this trivial issue. What about `useMemo` or `useCallback` hooks? Will they be of any help here? Any ideas on how to implement them here?